# Javascript regular expression for URL validation

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I want the regular expression to validate the URL with below condition,

1. It should start with http or https
2. It should end with the valid domain.
   Ex: .com or .in but after the . can have any string. Specially, check whether the `.` is there and there is a string following the `.`.

Valid URL: `http://www.cnn.com`

Invalid URLS:

```
htt://www.yahoo.com
http://www.yahoo.
http://www.yahoo
```

I have compose the regular expression as below.

```
/^(http|https):\/\/[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,;]+([\-\.]{1}[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/
```

It worked fine for most of the scenarios.

But if I enter `http://www.yahoo` didn't validate correctly, but If I enter `http://www.google` it throws the validation error.

Can anybody please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$
```

Comment: found it useful.....Thnx

Comment: It didnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following reg exp to match the urls

```
^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$
```

Check it here

https://www.regex101.com/r/jU7iT2/1